# Reverse git revert and push

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-revert

Here is my commit history

https://github.com/ClimateMind/climatemind-backend/commits/develop

I want to undo everything from January 17th. ("NetworkX only loads once" to "fixing")

I accidentally pushed straight to develop instead of creating a feature branch. I tried to fix this with a revert, which reversed a merge and really screwed up the branch. I then tried to merge master (which has all the newest and correct code) into develop, which didn't really work. And tried to fix it a few other ways after.

Nothing has worked so far. How can I undo the commits mentioned above and undo the damage I've caused? It's a shared repo if that makes a difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just push an old "correct" commit: `git push origin +<hash>:develop`. Find the hash of the right commit and replace `<hash>` with that.

Comment: Will that work even if the last correct commit was a merge?

Comment: @iBug this did not work "Cannot force-push to this protected branch"

Comment: Go to the repository settings and disable protection for that branch.